# Is there a notion of an S1-ification of a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given an arbitrary scheme $X$, there is a notion of its reduction $X_{\operatorname{red}} \to X$.

A well-known fact says that a scheme is reduced if and only if it satisfies Serre's condition R0 and S1. Hence the reduction is an R0 + S1-ification of a scheme.

Now let's say I don't want to make the scheme fully reduced but just want to eliminate all its embedded components. That is, I still want to keep some non-reducedness data.

Is there a notion of such an S1-ification of a scheme?

Comment: Have you looked at Theorem 2.9 of this paper of Kestutis Cesnavicius? https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~kestutis.cesnavicius/macaulayfication.pdf

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you very much, that seems exactly what I was looking for!